# Unknown app domain

Tags: debugging, iis, windbg, sos

When inspecting a dump file from our application in NTSD, I ran the `!DumpDomain` SOS command. I was expecting to see just the system, shared and default app domains, but in addition the was a domain called `/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130793976001194923` which had loaded quite a few assemblies.

Where does this app domain come from and what is the purpose? Our app is hosting IIS - is IIS creating this app domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, IIS creates an AppDomain per website like

```
/LM/W3SVC/2/Root/Website1-x-xxxxxxx
/LM/W3SVC/2/Root/Website2-x-xxxxxxx
```

If one of the .NET application crashes, it will not affect the others.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691263%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> When a request first enters managed code (managed modules or handlers), the IIS ManagedEngine module creates an application domain. The application domain then performs necessary processing tasks, such as authenticating a user with Forms authentication or other application services provided by managed code.

Comment: Thank you. Still not sure I get it though. How it is decided what is put in the default app domain and what is put in the one IIS creates? Some assemblies (like System.Web.dll) seems to be in both default and W3SVC app domain, is it supposed to be like that or could it be that we are failing to use strong named assemblies where we are supposed to?

Comment: @iCediCe: hmm, sorry, I can't answer that part. Perhaps you want to ask a new question about that so that it gets additional attention.